# Which port does imap_open use

Tags: php, imap

This is my code:

```
  $server = '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert}';
  $imap_connection = imap_open($server, $login, $password);
  $mailboxinfo = imap_mailboxmsginfo($imap_connection);
  $messageCount = $mailboxinfo->Nmsgs;
```

Its throwing some errors .

```
Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert} in /home2/booksby/public_html/anonymousemail.php on line 13
```

Googling suggests that the problem is due to some firewall issues. And my hosting provider is asking me which port does my php script uses.

So can someone tell me which port needs to opened for the above to work ? is it 993 ? Any way I can find out for sure ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS IBM states in [their documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_CHANGING_THE_DEFAULT_IMAP_PORT_STEPS.html):

> Choose 143 (default) to use the industry standard port for IMAP
>   connections over TCP/IP. You can specify a different port, but 143
>   works in most situations. When specifying a nonstandard port, make
>   sure the port is not reserved for another service. Port numbers can be
>   any number from 1 to 65535.

```
// To connect to an IMAP server running on port 143 on the local machine,
// do the following:
$mbox = imap_open("{localhost:143}INBOX", "user_id", "password");
```

for further reference  [see this link of php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php)

as by @max

143 is the default /insecure/ port for IMAP. In the wild, most servers require SSL, which is on port 993.

Comment: where do I choose this ? in this line? `$server = '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert}';`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams its just a example how to use in the above link there is full explanation

Comment: 143 is the default /insecure/ port for IMAP.  In the wild, most servers require SSL, which is on port 993.

Comment: You need to be clearer when copying words from a manual. Please quote anything that you have drawn from another source, along with a proper link as I have done above. This makes it clear that you did not write the above language.